# AngularJS - How do I capture JSON returned from a GET service method regardless of http status returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have an AngularJS app that I want to alert or capture the message of the following two returned JSON values, either on success or failure.

Two problems occur. On status code 500 I can not get the Message value of the returned JSON I get `undefined` when I try to alert `msg`.  On success I can not parse the JSON either.

**Message in Network console**

```
GET inviteUsers 500 Internal Server Error

{"Message":"Users are not available"}
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

**JSON on failure - returns status code 500**

```
{"Message":"Users are not available"}
```

**JSON on success**

```
{"Message": "Invitations sent successfully"}
```

**Controller Method**

```
$scope.inviteUsers = function(){
  var msg = JSON.parse(createNewUserService.inviteUsers().query()["Message"]);
}
```

**Service Method (Method GET)**

```
var _inviteUsers = function(){

  return $resource(serviceBase + 'inviteUsers',
{
});
};
```

Comment: So, What do you want to do? Make function save to use even when status code is is 500? When 500 you won't parse nothing, since nothing is returned (`undefined`)

Comment: I just need to capture the JSON "Message" value returned from the service message call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following helped achieve the desired result.  The key was to use angularjs promises.

```
var msg;
$scope.inviteUsers = function(){
  var inviteUsers = createNewUserService.inviteUsers().query();
  inviteUsers.$promise.then(function(data){
   msg = JSON.parse(data).Message;
   notify(msg);
  },
  function(error){
    msg = "No invitations sent";
    notify(msg);
  });
}
```

Comment: teşekkür ederim (Thank You) :)

Answer (score 1):

In fail condition you can access your message in error callback function

```
var msg;
var inviteUsers = createNewUserService.inviteUsers().query();
inviteUsers.$promise.then(function(data) {
    // success handler
    msg = JSON.parse(data)["Message"];
}, function(error) {
    // error handler
    msg = JSON.parse(error)["Message"];
});
```

Comment: For some reason alert(msg) does not display, however I am unsure the cause.   Still I see in my network console the row for this api call to be red colored with status 500.

Comment: does 500 response from server returns any message ?

Comment: Yes, please see edits, the JSON returned is {"Message":"Users are not available"} while the network console history for this request indicates error because error 500 code is returned and is red colored.

Comment: you can check  it inside the error callback function(error) {
    // error handler
    console.log(error) 
}

Comment: Thanks @salih, just re ran with modifications and received no message in console.

Comment: @salith, thank you. I managed to get the alert to show up with promises.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `Message` property wrong.

So update this:

```
var msg = JSON.parse(createNewUserService.inviteUsers().query()["Message"]);
```

to:

```
var msg = JSON.parse(createNewUserService.inviteUsers().query()).Message;
```

Update:

Regarding fail conditions, we should check it first if there's a response or the response is valid.

```
var msg = "Users are not available";
var resp = createNewUserService.inviteUsers().query();
if(resp)
  msg = JSON.parse(resp).Message;
```

Comment: Under fail conditions the network under the browser inspector returns 500 internal server error.  Even alert(JSON.parse(createNewUserService.inviteUsers().query()).Message);  does not produce an alert dialog.

Comment: Thank you Robin, I would need to only call the service method once because each time I call it, I initiate a  userInvitation call on the server.

Comment: @Vahe Ahh jizz, stupid mistake. You're right, updated my answer again.